# define matrix elements with loops

Tags: python

I want to define a single column zero matrix in Python and then using "for" and "if" loops associate some values to its element. My code is as follows:

```
import numpy as np

n=10
a=0
b=1 
d=(b-a)/(n+1)
x=np.zeros((n, 1))
v=np.zeros((n, 1))

for j in range(1,n):
    x[j]=j*d

if (x[j]>=0.4):
        v[j]=600

elif (x[j]<=0.6):
            v[j]=600
else:
            v[j]=0
```

I expect that v[5] and v[6] equal to 600 and others be zero but i faced with :

```
[[  0.]
 [  0.]
 [  0.]
 [  0.]
 [  0.]
 [  0.]
 [  0.]
 [  0.]
 [  0.]
 [600.]]
```

Can you kindly help me. Many thanks.

Comment: Is your indentation correct? Do you instead intend to have `if`/`elif`/`else` inside the `for` loop? At the moment, you only do the checks once you break out of the loop. Indentation is important in python.

Comment: Which version of python are you using to run this program?

Comment: If you are using Py2.7 then `d=(b-a)/(n+1)` will be equal to `0` unless you have `from __future__ import division` because they are all `int`s and Py2.7 will use integer division. Use `float(n+1)` so you have a `float` and use float division.

Comment: @roganjosh in addition to the indentation problem, integer division would also be an issue with the above code in running Py2.7. There is also probably with an issue with the conditionals - I'm assuming the OP meant `if 0.4 <= x[j] <= 0.6:` vs. the 2 conditions which makes the `else:` an impossible branch.

Comment: Is there a reason you want to do this with loops in the first place? Why not just `x = np.arange(n) * d`, then `v[(x >= 0.4) & (x <= 0.6)] = 600`?

Comment: @abarnert mentioned below :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you meant between `0.4` and `0.6` set the value to `600`, then you need to indent the `if` condition into the `for` and make the test a single test, e.g.:

```
In []:
for j in range(1, n):
    x[j] = j*d
    if 0.4 <= x[j] <= 0.6:
        v[j] = 600
    else:
        v[j] = 0
v

Out[]:
array([[  0.],
       [  0.],
       [  0.],
       [  0.],
       [  0.],
       [600.],
       [600.],
       [  0.],
       [  0.],
       [  0.]])
```

Note: if you are running Py2.7 you will also need:

```
d=(b-a)/float(n+1)
```

You can do this natively with numpy:

```
In []:
x = np.arange(n) * d
v = np.zeros((n, 1))
v[(x >= 0.4) & (x <= 0.6)] = 600
v

Out[]:
array([[  0.],
       [  0.],
       [  0.],
       [  0.],
       [  0.],
       [600.],
       [600.],
       [  0.],
       [  0.],
       [  0.]])
```